# Make a loop to have, for each name, exactly the same years avalaible in a dataframe and report the result in a dataframe using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset unbalanced, and if for a name, I have the four years (2010 2011 2012 2013) I want to repport the rows that respect this condition into a dataframe.
Here is what i have (for illustration):

| Année | Name | Rd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | x | 5 |
| 2010 | x | 2 |
| 2011 | x | 3 |
| 2012 | x | 5 |
| 2012 | x | 5 |
| 2013 | x | 7 |
| 2012 | y | 1 |
| 2013 | y | 2 |
| 2013 | y | 4 |
| 2010 | z | 4 |
| 2010 | z | 0 |
| 2011 | z | 1 |
| 2011 | z | 3 |
| 2012 | z | 5 |
| 2012 | z | 6 |
| 2013 | z | 4 |
| 2013 | z | 3 |
| 2013 | z | 7 |

And what I actually want

| Année | Name | Rd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | x | 5 |
| 2011 | x | 3 |
| 2012 | x | 5 |
| 2013 | x | 7 |
| 2010 | z | 4 |
| 2011 | z | 3 |
| 2012 | z | 6 |
| 2013 | z | 4 |
| 2010 | z | 0 |
| 2011 | z | 3 |
| 2012 | z | 5 |
| 2013 | z | 3 |

I've used dplyr and tidyverse function to do t bu i never get the result i want. I think a loop or a function woul be better but i o not know how to do. can you help me please? I am a new user of R loopings and function progamming.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Name) %>%
      filter(n_distinct(Année) == 4)
```